# Xcode 'NSinteger' (aka'int')? were do this goes?

Tags: xcode

```
NSString *nssHighscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bounce the ball upwards by tilting or touching where you want it to go. Bounce on the green platforms in order to move up. If you miss a platform and fall, it's game over.%lu",highscore];
```

Xcodes asks: 'NSinteger' (aka'int')

Were do i have to put this 'NSinteger' (aka'int') on the code.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%lu` is for an `unsigned long` integer. Use `%d` if you want to specify the format for an `int` integer. Apple has a table of these and other format specifiers on its [Developer Connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) site.